# How do I run a python/pygame script with command-line arguments?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm not very experienced with python beyond the basics, but I'm trying to run a pygame written by someone else. However, the game uses some initial inputs set by sys.argv, which I've deduced are the command-line arguments. Because I don't know how to include these when running the script, they don't exist, and thus I get "IndexError: list index out of range" every time I try. I've been researching this for hours and I can't find anything that is even remotely helpful. I'm using a Mac, if that's relevant.

More generally, what are some good resources for learning intermediate-advanced python? I know how to write basic scripts like for a game of hangman or rock paper scissors, but when I look at the code for anything useful it largely looks like gibberish to me. And as I've been troubleshooting all the problems I've been running into while trying to figure out how to get this script to work, I've found that none of the information online seems consistent at all. I'll find 10 different websites, each providing a different solution to my problem, and most of the time none of them work.

Comment: I answered your first question, but your second would be better directed to a forum like https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython that deals in open-ended questions and the psychology of learning to program.

If you have access to the source of the game, you could also just edit it to make it provide default values when sys.argv has no extra arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Command-line arguments are set simply by running the file from a [command prompt](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/chdos.htm) and adding them in space-separated format:

```
my_script.py myArg 77 "and so on..."
```